# Change the icon in About Box

Tags: c++, mfc

Could you tell me as to how do I change the default image that is displayed in an About Box? The one that comes default with MFC as three boxes. I would want to change that to my present icon that I have created using MFC. My icon works but I just need to change the picture/image in my About Box.

Thanks for your prompt replies.

Cheers.

Comment: That is such an detailed description, that I wish was you were more discreet.

Comment: Wouldn't it be like just a copy paste thing?

Comment: The problem with this question is that you are not specific about what you mean. What icon? The one in the caption bar, or one displayed in the client area. And how is your About box implemented? Be more specific.

Comment: Really love this website by the way. People are too prompt and fast in replying to queries.

Comment: If you really love this website, edit your question to be more specific, and then add your own answer, and accept it as the "accepted answer". This way, when someone else has the same problem, they can learn from you, even years from now. Or, delete this question entirely.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Done that now.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A typical MFC application has the About dialog as part of the resource file that can be edited in the WYSIWYG editor.  Open your projects `.rc` file, and click on the About Box dialog (the default IDD is IDD_ABOUTBOX).  Right click on the Icon and select properties.  From there you can change the icon that is used.  Usually you would do this by adding additional icon resources to your application and specifying the new ID.  Optionally, you could simply change the existing icon resource (by default it is IDR_MAINFRAME).